# Mismatched Union in Snowflake - dynamic approach instead of dummy columns?

Tags: union, snowflake

As far as I understand, in snowflake, the union works as follows-
Fails if there are a different number of columns.
Stitches together columns based on order alone, not names.

Well that's unfortunate.

Say you have Table Alpha with columns a,b,c, x,y,z ... and Table Beta with columns a,b,c, h,i,j.

Now imagine there's 100 columns and you don't want to write a bunch of "null as h" and order the columns correctly.

Is there dynamic way to write a union -- maybe involving a full outer join -- in snowflake so that it simply stitches together like-named columns, appends new columns with null, and the order doesn't matter? That would be more robust for my purposes.

Comment: You can try something like explained here [Loop through and combine schemas/tables with UNION_ALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730579/loop-through-and-combine-schemas-tables-with-union-all#59091023) . I wouldn't recommend dynamic approach as you might face other problems, see this [EXAMPLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-query#examples).  [General Usage Notes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-query)